# Can I use html5 Websockets with windows domain authentication?

Tags: html, websocket, coldfusion

Our setup is like this: we use a coldfusion 10 server, and files are on a local intranet. Users use a domain login to access any files over https. I'm interested in using html5 websockets, but the first attempt gave me an error because no credentials were supplied. Is there a way around this? If not, is there a recommended technology for this scenario?

The user does log in on the client side. If it's possible, what I'd really like to do here is pass those credentials when making the connection to the server.

Comment: Did you attempt to use ColdFusion to obtain any credentials?

Comment: User logs in on the client side. Can I supply those over socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to supply the `authentication` header to your web socket server before the elevation to web socket read that and send it back in the headers for the elevation (first frame) then when the browser connects it should have the authentication it needs.

if your using a custom authentication E.G in page not `authentication` header you can also do this by passing any custom header to your server.

Or mandate that the first thing your web client sends is the authentication details this could be something like `{username_hash}.{password_hash}` if they don't close the socket to them.

Comment: I'll give this a try later this week and return here with the results, but you're the only one who helped at all so I'm giving you the bounty either way.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this.
You're now responsible for sending and encrypting the authentication credentials yourself, bypassing something that already works and is tested.

Anyone can snoop on an unencrypted websocket port. Use HTTPs for an intranet, use stable solutions, don't reinvent this wheel because it tickles your fancy.

In a couple of years some colleague will have to maintain this and will have to figure out how your homebrew version works versus something that's solid like plain browser authentication.

My advice: Leave this to the browser and to well-tested coldfusion libraries.

Comment: As far as I have been able to find, there are no such cf libraries.  Using cf10 and the coldfusion websockets can't even do wss. Anyway the intranet is over https and the socket is going to be on the same network. I'm wondering if maybe websockets just aren't the right solution for me.

Comment: No one can snoop an unencrypted websocket server as your not allowed them on anything but `localhost/127.0.0.1` other wise they must be using `WSS` which uses a SSL Certificate, secondly the browser does not support authentication on WebSockets you have to implement it in some form.

Comment: I didn't mean in the browser context, but more global. With a simple package capture tool I could pull those straight from the wire, or out of thin air on unencrypted wifi. 

My point was: If you send credentials, don't send those over an unencrypted pipe like a non-WSS socket.

Comment: @SchizoDuckie that's what i was saying the Web Socket Specification outlines that on public IP Address or DNS lookup it must be using WSS so you can't packet sniff them without breaching the SSL Certificate, i know what packet sniffing is done and the easiest example would be a MITM attack on a network, and you wont be able to read it due to the SSL Encryption used in WSS, it's impossible to MITM local loop-back address as it does not go out to any network.